# Gdal.BuildVRT not creating any output

Tags: gdal, raster-conversion, gdalbuildvrt

I am trying to create a mosaic of all the images in file_list, Using:

```
> vrt_options = gdal.BuildVRTOptions(resampleAlg='cubic', addAlpha=True)
>     gdal.BuildVRT('C:\\my.vrt', file_list, options=vrt_options)
```

And file_list is a path of all the files i want merged.

> ```
>  'file_list'
>     ['C:\\fasih\\Test_combine\\1974106.mat.tif',
>      'C:\\fasih\\Test_combine\\1974107.mat.tif',
>      'C:\\fasih\\Test_combine\\1974108.mat.tif',
>      'C:\\fasih\\Test_combine\\1974109.mat.tif',
>      'C:\\fasih\\Test_combine\\1974110.mat.tif',
>      'C:\\fasih\\Test_combine\\1974111.mat.tif',
>      'C:\\fasih\\Test_combine\\1974112.mat.tif']
> ```

I get this output in Notebook, but nothing is saved in my drive.

```
<osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x000002180B46F5D0> >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. When the vrt is returned as a dataset, you can use this dataset to invoke `FlushCache()` which made the problem for me disappear. I can remember that this was not necesarry before, but this solved the problem for me.

```py
ds = gdal.BuildVRT('C:\\my.vrt', file_list, options=vrt_options)
ds.FlushCache()
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error and found a rather confusing solution by chance.

I saved the result of the `BuildVRT()` command in a variable and used it almost the same way you did. I used glob to build a list of all PNG files in my test folder:

```
import gdal
import glob

testSet = gdal.BuildVRT('/home/testfolder/test.vrt'), glob.glob('/home/testfolder/Mumbai/data/annotation/*.PNG'))
```

After that I used ReadAsArray() on the variable:

> testSet.ReadAsArray()

After this, the .vrt file appeared in the file explorer.

---

I can't quite explain why this happens and I surely don't think the commands are intended to be used this way.
I am using Python 2.7 and GDAL 2.3.2

I also suspect the Dataset read via `.ReadAsArray()` does not necessarily have to  be the dataset you want written to the hard disk in order for this to work.

**Can somebody solve the mystery why this works???**